# Polynomial time verifier for $\overline { EQ_{CFG}}$

Tags: time-complexity, context-free

How to find, or prove impossible, apolynomial time verifier for $\overline { EQ_{CFG}}$?

$\overline { EQ_{CFG}}$ means all pairs G and H, which are CFGs such that L(G) is not equal to L(H)

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231187/an-efficient-way-to-determine-if-two-context-free-grammars-are-equivalent?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Language_equality